# How can I draw antenna beam-like diagram with latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I would like to draw beams pointing towards any angle of my choice as shown in the picture. Can anyone help with the latex code please?  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I do not claim that this is a realistic representation of the power of the field emitted by an antenna. This is just to say that you can do parametric plots with `tikz-pgf`, with which this question is tagged.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=51] 
  ({180+18*sin(\t)}:{4*pow(sin(\t/2),3)});
 \draw plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=51] 
  ({225+12*sin(\t)}:{6*pow(sin(\t/2),3)});
 \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label=right:$x$]{}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Schrödinger's cat. This is exactly what I am wanting to do. Cheers!